# Ruby 1.9.1 rvm install fails

Tags: 11.04, ruby

I am trying to run this command to get ruby 1.9.1 working on my system:

```
rvm install 1.9.1
```

It says "error running make" and when I cat the log file this is the compile error I am getting:

```
gcc -I. -I../../.ext/include/x86_64-linux -I../.././include -I../.././ext/openssl -DRUBY_EXTCONF_H=\"extconf.h\"    -fPIC  -O2 -g -Wall -Wno-parentheses  -fPIC  -o ossl.o -c ossl.c
ossl.c:118:1: error: unknown type name ‘STACK’
ossl.c:119:1: error: unknown type name ‘STACK’
make[1]: *** [ossl.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/var/cache/ruby-rvm/src/ruby-1.9.1-p431/ext/openssl'
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

So whats up with this?  How do I get ruby 1.9.1 working under ubuntu 11.04?

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue? I have the same problem on Debian. It seems that ruby 1.9.1 is not compatible with openssl 1.0.0.

Comment: @Mladen Jablanović  Sort of.  I had to pull down the latest source for openssl,  build it,  and then override ruby's openssl path (or replace the current build of openssl).

Answer (score 2):

STACK appears to be a typedef which is defined in `/usr/include/openssl/stack.h` on my system.

This file is provided by `libssl-dev` according to dpkg - do you have that package installed?

Answer (score 2):

According to the latest version of RVM on my own system, you need the following in order to compile a Ruby on Ubuntu 11.10:

`build-essential openssl libreadline6 libreadline6-dev curl git-core zlib1g zlib1g-dev libssl-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt-dev autoconf libc6-dev ncurses-dev automake libtool bison subversion`

I suggest you install them, and then run `rvm reinstall 1.9.1` to cleanup the 1.9.1 code and install it.

Comment: the current list of required libs can be listed with `rvm requirements`.

1.9.1 is very old version, it does not have much attention from community, you could build it with applying patches for ruby-1.8.6 - openssl integration `rvm reinstall 1.9.1 --patch $rvm_path/patches/ruby/1.8.6/openssl-1.0.patch,patches/ruby/1.8.6/no_sslv2.diff` there are more patches that could help `find $rvm_ruby/patches/ruby/ -type f`